# Mailchimp - API equivalent to Lists Webhook

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We can't setup a Webhook for security reasons so we would like to make a request to the Mailchimp API to get the same information that is contained in the Lists webhook (subscribes, unsubscribes, updates etc) and perform this daily.

I've been looking at the Mailchimp API docs and under the Lists section I can't see anything that would allow us to do a GET for all "list activities" similar to what is contained in the Lists webhook.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the same information via the Mailchimp API that is contained in the Lists webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this endpoint:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#

which you can call using the Query String parameter:

since_last_changed - Restrict results to subscribers whose information changed after the set timeframe

So far this is the closest that I have found.